# flask socketIO - incompatible with arduino Client

Tags: flask, arduino

I tried 'simple websocket server' by 
https://github.com/dpallot/simple-websocket-server

```
 from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket

clients = []
class SimpleChat(WebSocket):

def handleMessage(self):
   for client in clients:
      if client != self:
         client.sendMessage(self.data)
         #client.sendMessage(self.address[0] + u' - ' + self.data)

def handleConnected(self):
   print(self.address, 'connected')
   print(self.request)
   for client in clients:
      client.sendMessage(self.address[0] + u' - connected')
   clients.append(self)

def handleClose(self):
   clients.remove(self)
   print(self.address, 'closed')
   for client in clients:
      client.sendMessage(self.address[0] + u' - disconnected')

server = SimpleWebSocketServer('', 5000, SimpleChat)
server.serveforever()
```

and I'm using Wemos D1 for arduino board. below is the code.
https://github.com/morrissinger/ESP8266-Websocket/blob/master/examples/WebSocketClient_Demo/WebSocketClient_Demo.ino

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h>

const char* arduino_id = "00000000"; // I gave the board an  id
const char* ssid     = "SSID";
const char* password = "password";
char path[] = "/";
char host[] = "10.1.1.61";

WebSocketClient webSocketClient;

// Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
WiFiClient client;

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(230400);
  delay(10);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  // Connect to the websocket server
  if (client.connect(host, 5000)) 
  {
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
  } 
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");

  }

  // Handshake with the server
  webSocketClient.path = path;
  webSocketClient.host = host;
  if (webSocketClient.handshake(client)) 
  {
    Serial.println("Handshake successful");
  } else 
  {
    Serial.println("Handshake failed.");
  }

}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println("got in to loop");
  String data;

  if (client.connected()) 
  {
    webSocketClient.getData(data);
    if (data.length() > 0) 
    {
      Serial.print("Received data: ");
      Serial.println(data);

    }

    // capture the value of analog 1, send it along
    //pinMode(1, INPUT);
    //data = "kimchi";

    //webSocketClient.sendData(data);

  } 
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
  }

  // wait to fully let the client disconnect
  delay(3000);

}
```

and It's working.

The problem is the arduino client doesn't work in flask websocketIO below.
it says "handshake failed"
(When I replace the server from 'simpleWebServer' to 'flask-SocketIO server', error message pops up)

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO

    from SimpleWebSocketServer import SimpleWebSocketServer, WebSocket

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
    socketio = SocketIO(app)
    from flask_socketio import send, emit

    @app.route("/")
    def sayHi():
        print(request.headers)
        return "hi browser"

    @app.route('/index')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html', async_mode=socketio.async_mode)

    @socketio.on('message')
    def handle_message(message):
        send(message)

    @socketio.on('json')
    def handle_json(json):
        send(json, json=True)

    @socketio.on('my event')
    def handle_my_custom_event(json):
        emit('my response', json)

    @socketio.on('connect')
    def test_connect():
        print('Client connected')
        emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})

    @socketio.on('disconnect')
    def test_disconnect():
        print('Client disconnected')

    @socketio.on_error()
    def chat_error_handler(e):
        print('An error has occurred: ' + str(e))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

below is the error message and header from client

```
Content-Type: text/plain
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 10.1.1.61
Sec-Websocket-Key: 9eYtRDJj/SJ1MDMFsbT22w==
Sec-Websocket-Protocol: 
Sec-Websocket-Version: 13


10.1.1.84 - - [19/May/2017 16:14:26] code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x87\x00')
10.1.1.84 - - [19/May/2017 16:14:26] " " 400 -
```

I don't know what is the problem. I checked header from client side
but there is no \x87\x00 in anywhere.
It would be best if you find out the main cause... but if you recommand other flask-websocket library or arduino library, I would be grateful also.
Could you guys please resolve this?
Thank you in advance.

PS: I checked documents below, but it didn't help.
    developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Comment: [please set the option of cors_allowed_origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60500012/8866585)